# What is the purpose of the special parameter "_" (single underscore) in environment?

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to understand how the environment variable `_` can be used. Below is an example of using it:

```
$ echo $_

$ echo $_
echo

$ ls non-existant-filename
ls: cannot access 'non-existant-filename': No such file or directory

$ echo $_
non-existant-filename
```

- First it returns nothing
- Second it returns the last command used
- Last it returns the last parameter used

This might be a handy variable for bash scripts but only if it's function is fully understood.

---

### Some useful applications of `_`

I found some useful applications of `_`.

#### `_` contains the last filename you can recycle

In this example `_` is used to keep the last filename which you can reuse in subsequent commands without retying it.

```
$ ll ~/python/scroll1.py
-rwxrwxrwx 1 rick rick 2384 Dec 27 09:15 /home/rick/python/scroll1.py*

$ $_
# The python program ~/python/scroll1.py is executed

$ cat $_
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   (... SNIP ... remaining contents of ~/python/scroll1.py appears on screen)
```

- First command uses `ll` to list a python script filename. The filename is saved to `_` for future use.
- Second command `$_` runs the python script.
- Third command `cat $_` lists the contents of the python script.

So the `$_` variable/parameter can save some typing.

#### `_` contains the last program run

Here's an example of differences between `env` and `printenv` updating the `_` variable/parameter:

```
$ env > env.txt

$ printenv > printenv.txt

$ diff env.txt printenv.txt
66c66
< _=/usr/bin/env
---
> _=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Because a parameter wasn't passed to either command, the `_` isn't updated with the last used parameter as in the previous example but, it is updated with the last command used.

Also noticed how `_` is updated **before** the commands `env` and `printenv` are executed because `_` it appears in the output.

Comment: Not a CS pro but this is a nice variable to use!

Comment: It's not an env variable, it's a special Bash parameter.  Basically an internal function/variable in Bash.  See my answer

Comment: @ThomasWard it kind of **is** an environment variable in the sense I discovered it using the commands `env` and `printenv`. But you cannot set it like a **regular** variable. For example using: `_="Hello World"`` followed by: `echo "$_"` doesn't display the new value. So as your answer states you cannot assign a value to it, the variable is automatically reset whenever you type a command.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix because it's not a *variable* - it's a builtin parameter.  Just like you can't assign a value to `$?` which is the exit code of the last process run.

Answer (score 14):

It's not an "Environment Variable".  It's a special Bash parameter that is handled specially by Bash.

From [the Bash Beginners Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_02.html) which explains this pretty well for Bash:

> **3.2.5. Special parameters**
>
> The shell treats several parameters specially. These parameters may
> only be referenced; assignment to them is not allowed.
>
> ...
>
> **`$_`**: The underscore variable is set at shell startup and contains the absolute file name of the shell or script being executed as passed
> in the argument list. Subsequently, it expands to the last argument to
> the previous command, after expansion. It is also set to the full
> pathname of each command executed and placed in the environment
> exported to that command. When checking mail, this parameter holds the
> name of the mail file.

<sup>(Format of the quote adjusted for Ask Ubuntu, but contains all the information)</sup>

They also include a nice example of how `$_` expands:

> ```
> franky ~> grep dictionary /usr/share/dict/words
> dictionary
>
> franky ~> echo $_
> /usr/share/dict/words
> ```

Explanation of the `_` parameter can also be found in the Bash manpage (`man bash`) under `PARAMETERS/Special Parameters` ([manpages.ubuntu.com](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#parameters) link for this section of the manpages)

Comment: The `_` parameter is explained in [`man bash`/PARAMETERS/Special Parameters](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/bash.1.html#parameters).

Comment: Also note that the specs say "The underscore **variable** is ..."

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Also note it shows up in `env` and `printenv` output. There is more to this "special parameter" than meets the eye.

Comment: @ThomasWard agreed it's a "special parameter" and not an "environment variable" and your answer is worthy of correcting that gaff. My gaff garners the two down-votes on my question I guess. Because `_` shows up in `env` and `printenv` it was an honest mistake calling it an environment variable. I've upvoted your answer BTW. The spirit of the question is still valid regardless of special parameter / environment variable designation, How can I use `$_`?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix ... which is why I provided the explanation of the parameter, *and* the examples they provided of a use of how it could be used.  How you utilize the 'arguments' provided to a prior command is entirely dependent on your needs, I'm not sure there's a *specific* example that we can give you of how exactly to use it.